# Google Drive API Revisions list() and get() methods not populating lastModifyingUser objects

Tags: google-drive-api

Using either the `list` or `get` methods against the Google Drive Revisions API, I'm getting very small result objects with no `lastModifyingUser` data. I can easily reproduce this in the API Explorer in the API docs for either method.

All revision responses return identical blank data like this:

```
"lastModifyingUserName": "",
"lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "isAuthenticatedUser": false
 }
```

The requests are fully authorized against a Google Apps for business account, and all the revisions were made by logged-in Google Apps users. I'm not having problems getting any other document metadata.

Comment: As of March 9, 2013, now I'm getting no `lastModifyingUser` information at all, just `kind`, `etag`, `id`, `selfLink`, `mimeType`, `modifiedDate`, `published`, and the list of `exportDocs`.

Comment: Specifically requesting the `lastModifyingUser` field using the API explorer just returns a blank result.

Comment: This now appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same result reproduced for Google Docs(Spreadsheet, Presentation, etc) file.

For now, you can use `Files.get()` which will return `lastModifyingUser` of latest change of the whole file, although you cannot view `lastModifyingUser` for each revision.

I will report this for you. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you! I'd really like to be able to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can get information about user from revision, but not from collection

```
var requestRevision = driveService.Revisions.Get(fileId, revision.Id);
requestRevision.Fields = "lastModifyingUser";
var lastModifyingUser= requestRevision.Execute();
Console.WriteLine($"Revision found for datetime: {revision.ModifiedTime}, revisionid: {revision.Id}, user: {lastModifyingUser.LastModifyingUser?.EmailAddress}");
```